# Should the tag "solution-verification not be removed (from the main site)?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, solution-verification

I think the tag [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) should be removed (burninated) due to the following points:

- According to some SE policy, each post must contain just **one** question. However, when someone tags a question [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification), this means that he/she wants others to answer question**s** on validity of *each* segment, required to be checked, of the provided solution, which actually needs answering many distinct questions. If anyone needs some feedback on some parts of his/her solution, he/she can narrow them down as far as possible and devote each post to **one** focused question.
- As it has been emphasized many times by the community leaders, Math SE is not for peer review. However, when some people see that such a tag exists, they may conclude that they can post their proposed proofs for unsolved problems as questions to be verified by others.
- Questions tagged [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) are likely not useful to others because they often only address reasoning and subjects which are not widespread.
- If people feel that they can ask such questions, this community may be filled up with show-off / rep-hunt questions, regarding that *they are in complete agreement with EoQS*.

Comment: I think a number of people do agree that this tag should be removed (iirc Xander) But I don't think your points are cogent. pt1: a solution to a simple problem of only one part should still be tagged the same way. If there are too many unrelated questions, just close as lack of focus. pt2: just because there's a number theory tag, does it mean we can ask arbitrary Qs about open problems in number theory? pt3: their subject matter is determined by the other tag(s); if they are not widespread then this is the other tag's fault. Some will agree on them being less useful to others tho

Comment: and pt4: I don't see why it would happen if it hasn't happened already. And removing the tag will not change the fact that they are/aren't in agreement with EoQS.

Comment: What does the ellipsis mean at the end? If your post is incomplete, why post it?

Comment: You seem to be making a lot of assumptions here but providing no evidence for them.  Since you're proposing the removal of a tag that's not really good enough.  You should back up your claims with proper evidence, and it wouldn't hurt to provide the (readily-available) statistics on the current level of usage of that tag.

Comment: Older discussions related to this tag: [What do you think is the largest problem facing Math.SE today (July 2015)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20944#20961) and [The problem with proof verification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119). (Both of them posted by @AsafKaragila, so I suppose he might have something to say on this issue.)

Answer (score 5):

The primary question concerning the tags [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) (and [its synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/synonyms) [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification)) is, in my opinion, whether questions of this type are allowed on this site.

At the moment, it seems that consensus of the community is that questions asking for solution verification are welcome on the site. (But several users have mentioned some concerns about such questions in various discussions on meta. For example, Asaf Karagila's posts [What do you think is the largest problem facing Math.SE today (July 2015)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20944#20961) and [The problem with proof verification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119).)

If the questions asking for solution verification are allowed, then we should definitely keep those tags. It is important to distinguish such questions from the "regular" questions.

If, at some point in the future, the community of this site decides that questions asking for solution verification are no longer allowed, then we should do something about these two tags. But even then, I wouldn't be in favor of complete removal.

To me, blacklisting the tags seems like a better option. This would mean that these tags can no longer be used on the new question. But we still would be able to distinguish older questions of this type. (I will add that a tag can be blacklisted without being removed from all questions, as discussed, for example, here: [Can we please have a “deprecated tag” feature?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28025))

In any case, the discussion what to do with these tags will only be needed if/when there is a clear decision that solution-verification question are no longer welcome.

EDIT: Only later I noticed this older question which also suggests to remove this tag: [Can I get [solution-validation] on my idea to remove this tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30009) (It is sad that I have forgotten about my own answer. On the other hand, I am glad to see that in my answer I have presented rather similar argument.)

Comment: I will also add a reminder of the suggestion, that the tags (proof-verfication) and (solution-verification) could be synonyms also on meta (since they are synonyms on the main site). See the [corresponding entry in the tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/tag-management-2021/33678#33678).