# "too broad" tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are some tags, that can be considered «too broad»:

For example

[abstract-algebra]:
The tag wiki says, that it is a tag for questions about [algebraic objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure)

However, most important classes of algebraic objects already have their tags:

[group-theory] for groups,

[semigroups] for semigroups,

[ring-theory] for rings,

[field-theory] for fields,

[linear-algebra] for vector spaces,

[modules] for modules,

etc.

And if you want to ask a question about general properties of algebraic structures, than your question will fall under [universal-algebra] category.

All aforementioned branches are relatively independent from each other and thus the reason to group them under such a large umbrella does not seem to be very obvious.

Another such tag is [discrete-mathematics]:

«the study of mathematical objects, that are fundamentally discrete»

This covers [combinatorics], [elementary-set-theory], [graph-theory], [finite-groups], [formal-languages], [automata], etc.

Such tags do not seem to be very informative, as they are applicable to a very large number of questions that neither are about similar structures nor share similar methods of solution. However if they exist and even are quite popular, that means they are probably useful for something else… What is the purpose of such tags?

Comment: I think the ability to add a general “umbrella” tag is useful. Not only for cases where picking a specific tag is difficult, but also for more loosely grouping questions.  It is slightly redundant sometimes, but I think two layers deep (general+specific) is not too complicated.

Comment: Yes, we had a discussion about the discrete mathematics tag. It's just hard to fix a tag with that size. Same for abstract algebra...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you mean this post: [I find (discrete-mathematics) problematic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17052)?

Comment: @Martin: I do...